# Python Flask Blog Message without format

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I have codes for a simple message blog that very body can leave message. One of the problems is that the message display from sqlite db is without format, e.g. without paragraph. How can I impove it (or add markdown enable)? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

main app py

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = db_conn()
    posts = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM table_posts').fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/create_new_post', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create_new_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.form['content']

        conn = db_conn()
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO table_posts (content) VALUES (?)', (content,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        return render_template('create_new_post.html')
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Simple Message Board
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <br>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text"> {{ post['content'] }} </p>
                <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ post['time_stamp'] }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The outcome i want is as follows:

```
Text of 1st line
Text of 2nd line
Text of 3rd line
```

But the actual content displayed is as follows:

```
Text of 1st line Text of 2nd line Text of 3rd line
```

Comment: I think you are trying to render the content as html not as string, like <p>[..]</p> you are getting this and you want [...] , right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, actually I want to display as html. But I am new to this so I do not know how to do.

Comment: for that you need to insert the data in form of html like `Text of 1st line <br> Text of 2nd line <br> Text of 3rd line`, then only safe filter will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to render the body as html not as text.

jinja autoescapes the text , you can stop autoescaping,
For that you can use the safe filter of jinja.

```
{{ post['content']|safe }}
```

You can also see the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but the text is still no format. The text displayed like   `1st para And 2nd para 3rd para 4th para` without the paragraph between the text

Comment: can you paste the text which you want to format and what is the result.

Comment: sorry? I still don't understand.can you edit your question and give a example of what are you trying to do. show the text coming from database and what you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to have the following result (each text line has a paragraph):
```Text of 1st paragraph  
Text of 2nd paragraph  
Text of 3rd paragraph  ```
But the text displayed now (only one line) is:
```Text of 1st paragraph Text of 2nd paragraph Text of 3rd paragraph```

Comment: I don't see any difference between both of them. maybe comment is making it look same I think you should edit you question and include the example in it.

Comment: sorry for my typing. I edited my question with update at the end of my question. Thank you.